# Interactive legend in D3 for Horizontally Stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js, filter, transition

I have created a horizontally stacked bar chart after referencing multiple examples on [D3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) portal.   I set out to to achieve following goals

1. Tooltip on chart
2. Mouse hover on legend to highlight corresponding data
3. Mouse click on legend to
   3.1. Change opacity of legend (unselect effect)

   3.2. filter data based on selection

   3.3. with transition effects

Was able to get #1, #2 & #3.1 requirements satisfied except for #3.2 & #3.3 i.e. data filtering based on legend selection with transition effects.

Here's sample code where I need help with data filtering and transition code upon clicking legend. Complete code on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SPaYIZxtSrO7ynH5byfl?p=preview)

```
.on("click", (function(d){
var y = "sqbar color-" + color(d).substring(1);
console.log("Class =" + y);
var opacity  = document.getElementsByClassName(y)[0].style.opacity;
console.log ("Old opacity =" + opacity);

if (opacity === "1") {
svg.selectAll(".sqbar.color-" + color(d).substring(1)).style("opacity", "0.2");
//svg.selectAll(".rect.color-" + color(d).substring(1)).remove();
}
else{
svg.selectAll(".sqbar.color-" + color(d).substring(1)).style("opacity", "1");
//svg.selectAll(".rect.color-" + color(d).substring(1)).d.enter().append();
}

opacity  = document.getElementsByClassName(y)[0].style.opacity;
console.log ("New opacity =" + opacity);
}))
```

Comment: When you say you want to filter by selection, exactly what do you want to happen? Do you want opacity of everything but your selection to reduce, so that it they seem to fade into the background. Or do you actually want to remove the things not selected? I'm quite new to d3 and I only know v4 not v3. This might be useful https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-v4-Bar-Chart-Highlight-Group/ . and also this example http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360 where you can click on the legend to remove all but your selection.

Comment: @ofey Based on whats selected in Legend, I wanted to remove the corresponding data from the graph. Remaining data should be adjusted and transitioned in the graph. The opacity of selection in Legend is reduced as to give impression of deselection effect. The data should be added back to the chart if the legend selection was on a legend item with reduced opacity.

Comment: You can filter data with dc.js however as far as I know this only works with d3 v3. I haven't tried to do what you want to do but I would approach it having the graph created in a draw() function. This would allow you to pass different data to it after the data had been filtered, i.e. the selected legend category removed. You will need to use the Update Pattern to enter() and exit() and remove() data.

Comment: Look at Bostock's example of the update pattern https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: Here is my own attempt to apply the update pattern to a bar chart https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Bar-Chart-Update-Pattern